# get key and value from HashMap within ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, key-value

I have a file that i get all the data and separate it into a HashMap.
The file looks something like this below.

Before the `:` is the `key` and after is the `value`

```
key1: 1
key2: 2
key3: 3
```

this is the code that puts the file data into the map ArrayList:

```java
protected List<Map<String, String>> yaml_parse(BufferedReader filename) throws IOException{

    String result;
    List<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    while ((result = filename.readLine()) != null) {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        String key = result.substring(0, result.indexOf(":"));
        String value = result.substring(result.lastIndexOf(":") + 2);
        map.put(key, value);
        list.add(map);
    }

    return list;
}
```

in another class where i call the function and println, this is the output

```
[{key1=1}, {key2=2}, {key3=3}]
```

So my Main question is, how do i get `key1` and have it return its value?

Comment: the what about list has two `Map` objects and each  `map` has `key1`?

Comment: the list has 3 map objects in it, which are: `[{key1=1}, {key2=2}, {key3=3}]`

Comment: Why on earth would you build a list of single-entry maps? That makes no sense. If you're using the map as a holder of a key/value pair, then stop being lazy and create a class, then have a list of that class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why you are creating a `List` of maps. A `Map` will let you put several key value pairs. Here is a way that would work:

```
protected Map<String, String> yaml_parse(BufferedReader filename) throws IOException{
    String result;
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    while ((result = filename.readLine()) != null) {
        //keyValue[0] = key, keyValue[1] = value
        String[] keyValue = result.split(": "); 
        map.put(keyValue[0], keyValue[1]);
    }

    return map;
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
Map<String, String> map = yaml_parse("myFile.yaml");
String key1Value = map.get("key1"); //Stores key1's value into key1Value
```

I think you might be using the wrong data structure. From your question, it seems like you want a `Map` only, not a `List` of `Maps`.

Answer (score 2):

So if you are interested in using java-8, if list of map contains any of entry with key as `key1` will return the first entry value else it will return the default value

```
list.stream().flatMap(map->map.entrySet().stream().filter(entry->entry.getKey().equals("key1"))).findFirst()
  .orElse(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry("key1", "default value")).getValue();
```

Just by using normal for loop

```
for(Map<String, String> map : list) {
        if(map.containsKey("key1")) {
            result = map.get("key1");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should look at changing your `List<Map>` to a `Map`. You can do this using:

```
Map<String, String> map = list.stream()
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

If you want to work with your current data structure, you can get the required value like this:

```
private Optional<String> getValue(List<Map<String, String>> list, String key) {
    return list.stream()
            .filter(m -> m.containsKey(key))
            .map(m -> m.get(key))
            .findFirst();
}
```

and use it as follows:-

```
Optional<String> value = getValue(list, "key2");
System.out.println(value.orElse(null));
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this is the data structure you want?

A map can contain more than 1 key/value pair. Why not have a single hashmap here, containing all 3 key/value pairs, at which point, you can just do:

```
map.get("key1")
```

and it'll still be fast even if you have millions of these.

If you are making single-size maps and putting them into an arraylist because you want to preserve order, use `LinkedHashMap`. If you need to be capable of dealing with repeated keys, use guava's `Multimap`, or make a `Map<String, List<String>>`.